# Why would Bluetooth Atheros want to access Skype?

Tags: windows, skype, bluetooth

I downloaded Skype and after running it, it says Bluetooth Atheros wants to access Skype. Why?

Comment: What device are you using - PC; Mobile; or maybe aSmartphone?

Comment: @Robrok: PC, as it has the Windows tag and Atheros is a PC company *afaik*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Bluetooth software has probably a function that allows you to **accept/deny calls if you have a device that supports that**; so, it just asks for confirmation in advance to allow devices that can connect to your computer to accept or deny calls.